# Upon trying to install ubuntu the install hangs on GRUB

Tags: system-installation, apple

When installing ubuntu I can reach the GRUB menu however after pressing either "Install Ubuntu" or "Install Ubuntu w/ Safe Graphics" the system locks up and usb power is cut. (I am assuming that as the keyboard RGB cuts after a few seconds)

To specify I am using an IMac with an i5-6600 @ 3.30Ghz and 8gb of ram. (Capable of running ubuntu) and it runs windows fine and I am currently trying to switch from windows to ubuntu. I am planning to use as a server but am willing to run the desktop version if it means more compatibility. The install hangs on ubuntu desktop and server. I have tried making the bootable USB with ventoy and rufus. I have tried rufus in both ISO & DD Mode and both have produced the same result. I am running ethernet so wifi drivers do not matter. My only issue is that hanging on grub.

Quick Update. I did a quick bit of checking and I discovered the model is a "IMac 27 Inch Late 2015" is that helps anyone.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you trying to install?

Comment: The Desktop LTS 20.04 I have also tried Server 20.04.4.